# How to save a variable token Globally and update it every 10 hours

Tags: java

I have a java application, where I need to make a rest call to an API with login credentials to get a token, The token has an expiry date, which is 10 hours from the time it was requested. All the other calls to their API's needs to be called with that token.

I need to save the token so that the login call is only made once in 10 hours, How can I achieve that?
I have tried creating a singleton class. But, I think multiple threads might try to refresh the token, during the expiry time.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CredentialsHolder {

    private static CredentialsHolder instance = null;
    private String loginToken;
    private Date loginTokenExpiry;

    private static final String API_BASE_URL_V1 = "https://api.com/rest";
    private static final String API_LOGIN_TOKEN_PATH = "token";
    private static final String API_USER_NAME = "userName";
    private static final String API_PASSWORD = "password";

    public static synchronized CredentialsHolder getInstance() {
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new CredentialsHolder();
        return instance;
    }

    private CredentialsHolder() {
        setAPICredentials();
    }

    private void refreshToken() {
        setAPICredentials();
    }

    private void setAPICredentials() {
        if (Calendar.getInstance().after(toCalendar(loginTokenExpiry))) {
            Map headers = new HashMap();
            headers.put("userName", API_USER_NAME);
            headers.put("password", API_PASSWORD);
            Map criteria = new HashMap();
            criteria.put("headers", headers);
            criteria.put("url", API_BASE_URL_V1 + API_LOGIN_TOKEN_PATH);
            Map response = new ExternalAPICaller().httpGet(criteria);
            Map responseHeaders = ((Map) response.get("headers"));
            System.out.println(responseHeaders);
            loginToken = (String) (responseHeaders.get("Token"));
            try {
                loginTokenExpiry = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a").parse((String) (responseHeaders.get("TokenExpiry")));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                loginTokenExpiry = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public String getAccessToken()  {
        if (Calendar.getInstance().after(toCalendar(loginTokenExpiry)))
            refreshToken();
        return loginToken;
    }

    public static Calendar toCalendar(Date date){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);
        return cal;
    }
}
```

Comment: If something is to be stored for hours, I'd go with a database. Likely you already have it in your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) for this. From the example docs:

```
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
class BeeperControl {
  private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
    Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

  public void beepForAnHour() {
    final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
      public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); }
    };
    final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle =
      scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
    scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
      public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
    }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
  }
}
```

You could create an instance of this `ExecutorService` and tell it to refresh the token at some interval.

But perhaps a simpler solution is to use thread synchronization to ensure only one token refresh happens when multiple threads are contesting for it. [`ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#tryLock%28%29) or `Semaphore` could be used to ensure only one thread is refreshing the token.

Comment: Good Answer. Let me add: Be sure to **shutdown the executor** when your app ends. Otherwise the background threads may continue running.